# ¿Cómo hacer web scrapping de una variable con php?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una pagina web ecommerce en la cual quiero que los precios se evalúen en base al precio del dólar. La moneda de mi pais no es estable entonces quiero registrar el float que aparece en esta pagina web https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/dolar.html (es el que dice Dolar Blue Compra). Intente con el siguiente codigo,

```
$dataweb = file_get_contents("https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/dolar.html");
$usds = NULL;

if (preg_match('|<div class="buy-value"><span class="currency">$</span>(.*?)</div>|is', $dataweb, $usd)) {
    $usds = (float)$usd;
}
```

Lo del (.*?) lo saque de acá (https://deerme.org/php/capturar-datos-de-otra-web-en-php) pero nose bien como se usa preg_match

En el html, la parte que quiero poner el precio seria:

```
<h2><?php echo MONEDA . number_format(($precio / $usds), 2, '.', ','); ?></h2>
```

Pero me tíra *Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero*

Si pudieran decirme como hacerlo o con que herramientas aprender lo agradeceria mucho;
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi manejo en expresiones regulares es penoso, así permíteme una solución alternativa.

Puedes ocupar [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) para cargar un html, por ejemplo:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile( 'https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/dolar.html' );
$usds  = $doc->getElementById("market-scrll-2")->childNodes[0]->childNodes[1]->childNodes[0]->childNodes[0]->childNodes[1]->childNodes[1]->nodeValue;
$usds =floatval($usds);
```

Con getElementById buscamos el elemento cuya Id es "market-scrll-2", que es el elemento más cercano con Id.

Luego buscamos por nodo usando childNodes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: En la imagen se ve un tbody, esto lo agrega el navegador, el código real no lo tiene.

Comprobación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, lo implemente y en la pagina y me tira muchísimos (+100) errores como este
** Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/dolar.html, line: 4 in D:\Programas\XAMPP\htdocs\daleeee\details.php on line 40**
según lo que vi son errores del código fuente que no fueron convertidos a HTML del link utilizado (pagina: cronista). Como podría solucionarlos todos?

Comment: @uliseswolo Al principio del php prueba colocar error_reporting(0); Recuerda que si mi respuesta te pareció satisfactoria puedes marcarla como aceptada (el visto verde) Saludos!

Comment: genial , me sirvió, sos muy bueno en esto